# How do I base a CSS property on another element that isn't the direct parent?

Tags: html, css, css-calc

For example, I would like to make 3 `div` columns which are 5%, 15% and 25% the width of the page (`body`), respectively.

Pseudo-Code (HTML):

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="d"></div>
</div>
```

Pseudo-Code (CSS):

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    height: calc(100% - 1em);
}

#a
{
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;

    background: grey;
}

#b
{
    width: calc(width(body) * 0.05);
    height: 100%;

    background: red;
}

#c
{
    width: calc(width(body) * 0.15);
    height: 100%;

    background: blue;
}

#d
{
    width: calc(width(body) * 0.25);
    height: 100%;

    background: green;
}
```

I would like to know how to do this without using scripts and definite numbers (such as `100px`), as a lot of answers (yes I have tried to Google for an answer) I've seen include these.

Comment: Did you try `width: 10%`?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to reference property value of specific element that is not a parent element. You could try css variables and store width in variable and then use it in calc, also to there are vw units to get width of the window.

Comment: Also **rows** shouldn't be different widths....that makes no sense in a table.

Comment: @Paulie_D Should I rewrite the question but with `div`s?

Comment: @Paulie_D I replaced the table with `divs`. Will that do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), or variables, to store your body's width. Then, you can use `calc()` to get a percentage of your body's width. You can access your variables by using `var(--your-css-variable)`.

Unfortunately, I think `vw`, absolute units, *and maybe `rem`* are the only valid units you can use on your body's width.

```css
:root {
    /* CSS variable for body's width */
    --width-body: 100vw;
}

html { height: 100%; }

body { 
    height: calc(100% - 1em); 
    width: var(--width-body);
}

#a {
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
    background: grey;
    
    /* Flexbox will give the children div's 
       their full height. */
    display:flex;
}

#b {
    /* 0.05 represents 5% of body's width */
    width: calc(var(--width-body) * 0.05);
    background: red;
}

#c {
    /* 0.15 represents 15% of body's width */
    width: calc(var(--width-body) * 0.15);
    background: blue;
}

#d {
    /* 0.25 represents 25% of body's width */
    width: calc(var(--width-body) * 0.25);
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your code snippet again. The blue and green boxes are outside the grey one.

Comment: That's because you set `height: 100%` for the inner `<div>` elements in your code. It would be helpful to make that clear in your question.

Comment: Neither code snippet achieves what I'm after. The RGB `div`s should be on the same line, like single-column rows.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The red, blue, and green `<div>`'s cannot be on the same line *(on one row)* and be on their own row. This is your question: *I would like to make 3 div rows which are 5%, 15% and 25% the width of the page (body), respectively.* If you want the three `<div>`'s to be on the same line, you need 1 row, not 3.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I fixed the question now.

Comment: Thank you. I used Flexbox on `#a` to let its children expand the full height.

Comment: Thanks. I don't mean to be that guy, but I'm in a bit of a 4 year question-ban and am trying to get upvotes, so would you mind upvoting this question in case you haven't?

Answer (score -3):

Try below

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#row1 {
    width: 10%;
}
#row2 {
    width: 30%;
}
#row3 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my rows are still the same width. Perhaps `div`s would be the way of approaching this problem.

Comment: I have rewritten my question to use `div`s instead of a table. Please rewrite your answer to suit the new pseudocode.

Comment: #a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#b {
 float: left;
    width: 10%;
}
#c {
 float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#d {
 float: left;
    width: 50%;
}